# document.body.appendChild(form) duplicates the form at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a form to filter values in a table. I am appending a form as a child to the document body and it is duplicating the form.
The top line of the form is:

```
<form id="form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e) } autoComplete="off">
```

The handleSubmit function is:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Running console.log(form) currently gives <form id="form" autoComplete="off">...</form>
    // When the following two lines are ran the form is duplicated at the bottom of the document body
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    this.props.onTriggerFilter(e);
    // Running console.log(form) now gives [form#form, form#form, form: form#form] 
    //This duplication stops me running the form again and adds another form at the bottom of the page
}
```

The onTriggerFilter function is:

```
onTriggerFilter = () => {
    // Ignore the lines upto the return statement
    var tags = this.state.filterData.tags;

    if(this.state.filterData.tag)
        tags.push(this.state.filterData.tag)

    var filterData = this.state.filterData;
        filterData.tags = tags;
        filterData.tag = '';
    // This returns an array of objects which are displayed in a table
    return this.getAssets(filterData).then(assets => {
        this.setState({
            assets: assets,
            filterData: filterData
        })
    });
}
```

How Do I get the form to stop duplicating itself?

Comment: Why don't you render the form in the react component instead of appending it to the document?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question quite literally is already present in your code:

```
// When the following two lines are ran the form is duplicated at the bottom of the document body
document.body.appendChild(form); // <--- this line adds "another" duplicate form to your HTML upon submitting it since it's in the handleSubmit function.
```

Edit yep, according to MDN's [appendChild docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) if a reference is given, it should simply move it and not duplicate it.

My Question in this case is, where are you getting that `form` var from which you are appending? That code is not present in the Question, my guess is that you're most likely not appending a reference but a standalone element thus causing the duplication.

Comment: `appendChild` does not _clone_ elements though; quote from MDN: _“If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node). This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position.”_ - so that doesn’t really explain why they would have two of them now …

Comment: Hmm are you sure you're supplying a reference and not a blank/new form element?

If you remove that line it'll stop duplicating for almost certain.

Comment: Hi. If I put var form = document.getElementById(form); above the appendChild line then I get the error message: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. If I console log form I get null. How do I solve that?

Comment: You need convert `var form = document.getElementById(form);` to `var form = document.getElementById('form');` (I put quotes around form so it's no longer a variable usage, instead it's a string).
Alternatively `var form = document.getElementById(form.id);` might also work.

Comment: I have now done this and it works infinitely many times but still duplicates the form everytime.


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();


    <form ref={this.myRef} id="form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e) } autoComplete="off">


    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const node = this.myRef.current;
        console.log('node', node);
        document.body.appendChild(node);
        this.props.onTriggerFilter(e);
        }

Comment: I tried both of those Campiotti and just got the same result

Comment: Hmm can you check one thing for me - how many elements with `id="form"` do you have upon initially loading the page (without submitting any form)?

I'm not really sure why it's not working as is since I've tested the same thing (no React though) and it worked just fine.


If there isn't more than one occurrence of an element with `id="form"`,  you should maybe look into how to append Elements to the body in ReactJS (this plugin might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-append-to-body ).